# Not able to get Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED events

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have created a broadcast receiver and registered it, but i am not able to receive the Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED events.

```
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
        addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
        addDataScheme("package")
        }

        intentFilter.priority = 999

        val rec = IntentReceiver()
        registerReceiver(rec, intentFilter)
```

This is my BroadcastReceiver class

```
class IntentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "TEST TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    val builder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, "worker_channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("App is installed")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

    val notificationManager: NotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(4, builder.build())

}}
```

I am not getting any events, however the same broadcast receiver works for intents like:

```
Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED
```

and also i am getting logs for PACKAGE_ADDED Events in Logcat as

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.gass.chimera.PackageChangeBroadcastReceiver
```

I have tested on android 11 and 12 every other intents are working fine except Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, am i missing anything or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue is resolved, i had to add query all packages permission for android versions after 10, don't know why it isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: this is brilliant! I have been struggling with the problem for few hours already, read pages of docs multiple times but only here I found the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Commenting to say thank you so much. I searched for this for SOOO long, went through probably a dozen or more SO posts as well as the documentation on the intent and this is the only thing I've found that made this work!